# Format string in python using sql.Literal

Tags: python, sql, json

I am executing this SQL query in a python script,  in the config_study dictionary (got from json file), I have provided objects, like start_date, study_name etc. I want to enable that start_date or end_date are optional, so if not provided I want to use default values like '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01'. If they are provided I would like to use them as it is now.

How to set a default value in this query for start_date=sql.Literal(config_study['start_date'])?

```
 import psycopg2
 from psycopg2 import sql

 def execute(conf, cur):
 config_study = conf['config_study']

    if 'start_date' not in config_study:
    config_study['start_date'] = '1900-01-01'

    if 'end_date' not in config_study:
    config_study['end_date'] = '1900-01-01'

    pre_query = sql.SQL(""" 

    INSERT INTO {{tmp_output_schema_name}}."config_set"
            ("study_id",
             "study_name",
             "study_type",
             "date_start",
             "date_end",
             "sales",
             "client")
        VALUES
            ({{study_id}},
             {study_name},
             {{study_type_shortname}},
             {start_date},
             {end_date},
             'edwin@gmail.co',
             'Persona client'); """).format(
                    study_name=sql.Literal(config_study['study_name']),
                    start_date=sql.Literal(config_study['start_date']),
                    end_date=sql.Literal(config_study['end_date']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably most readable way of doing this is to leave your code untouched, but precede it with the following:

```
if 'start_date' not in config_study:
    config_study['start_date'] = '1900-01-01'
if 'end_date' not in config_study:
    config_study['end_date'] = '1900-01-01'
```

so that missing values in `config_study` are filled with defaults.

Comment: my python scripts starts like this, and just for you to know I started learning python 15 days ago, so I don't know it. I set my script now to start like this, but it failed, do you know why?

Comment: This is unreadable. Please edit your original post to include the relevant part of the script.

Comment: The line below `def` should be indented - it is inside the function…

Comment: Actually, in the script it was, but I set your if code wrong, without indented, fixed and I am testing it now :), thanks